# UVM factory sequence generation strange behavior

Tags: verification, uvm

I have read '[seven separate sequence styles speed stimulus scenarios](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjbybHQ8bzgAhVLIzQIHYQWCe0QFjAAegQIABAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2Fverificationacademy-news%2FDVCon2013%2FPapers%2FMGC_DVCon_13_Seven_Separate_Sequence_Styles_Speed_Stimulus_Scenarios.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0C8TtQ6jFPfCe7ZSKYK7FI)' and want to try out the hierarchical sequence. Here, I have two atomic sequences FifoPush and FifoPop both extending from FifoSeqBase. Also, I wanted to create higher level abstraction sequence called FifoPushPop20 performing FifoPush followed by FifoPop. However, the testbench did not work the way I wanted and it took me while to figure out the errors --- two typos!

```
class FifoSeqBase extends uvm_sequence #(FifoTransact);
  `uvm_object_utils(FifoSeqBase)
...
endclass

class FifoPush  extends FifoSeqBase;
  `uvm_object_utils(FifoPush) 
...
endclass

class FifoPop  extends FifoSeqBase;
  `uvm_object_utils(FifoPush)         <- typo #1
...
endclass
```

In my FifoPushPop20 sequence, two sequences are started, but made the second typo, as shown below:

```
class FifoPushPop20  extends FifoSeqBase;
 ...
 task body();
    FifoPush push = FifoPush::type_id::create("push");
    FifoPush pop = FifoPop::type_id::create("pop");  <- typo #2
    push.start(m_sequencer);
    pop.start(m_sequencer);
 ...
 endtask
endclass
```

When I had two typos as shown above, there was no compile or run time errors.  Can I have an explanation why this error was not detected during compile time or run time? What happened was that the "typo #2" actually created FifoPush type object, not FifoPop object, even though I used FifoPop::type_id::create("pop").

Answer (score 1):

You were just lucky/unlucky* that you made both typos. Correct either and the code doesn't compile. With both typos, the first macro has expanded to a bunch of stuff related to the `FifoPush` class instead of the `FifoPop` class, which just happens to (a) still be legal and (b) is called by the second typo.

---

*delete as appropriate

---

It's always good to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
`include "uvm_macros.svh"

module M;

  import uvm_pkg::*;

  class FifoTransact extends uvm_sequence_item;
    `uvm_object_utils(FifoTransact)
    function new (string name = "");
      super.new(name);
    endfunction
  endclass

  class FifoSeqBase extends uvm_sequence #(FifoTransact);
    `uvm_object_utils(FifoSeqBase)
    function new (string name = "");
      super.new(name);
    endfunction
    task body; endtask
  endclass

  class FifoPush  extends FifoSeqBase;
    `uvm_object_utils(FifoPush) 
    function new (string name = "");
      super.new(name);
    endfunction
  endclass

  class FifoPop  extends FifoSeqBase;
    `uvm_object_utils(FifoPush)  //       <- typo #1
    function new (string name = "");
      super.new(name);
    endfunction
  endclass

  class FifoPushPop20  extends FifoSeqBase;
    `uvm_object_utils(FifoPushPop20)
    function new (string name = "");
      super.new(name);
    endfunction
    task body;
      FifoPush push = FifoPush::type_id::create("push");
      FifoPush pop = FifoPop::type_id::create("pop");  // <- typo #2
      push.start(m_sequencer);
      pop.start(m_sequencer);
    endtask
  endclass

endmodule
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/4c7V